# Elegant/built-in way of moving whole drawings around relative to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is there any built-in way in the `tikz` package for moving/positioning a whole set of paths and nodes relative to another set or to the document's page?

To illustrate what I mean, here is what I was working on:

[image: tikz figure screenshot]

As you can see, I placed a distinct drawing next to another one. But I think the way I achieved it isn't the simplest/most elegant solution: I've used a `tabular`.

```
\begin{minipage}{32em}\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
        \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(60:1cm)$);
        \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
        %
        \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$ \delta $}};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E)
        pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm,
        "\textcolor{red}{$\alpha$}", pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D)
        pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm,
        "\textcolor{dark green}{$\beta$}", pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)
        pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20, angle radius=1cm,
        "\textcolor{orange}{$\gamma$}", pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
        %
        \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
        \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
        \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
        \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
        \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm, right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};
        
        \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(60:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);
        
        \draw [thick, dark blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 60, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ \frac{\pi}{6} - \varepsilon $};
        
        \draw (46:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
        \draw (44:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
        \draw (76:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
        \draw (74:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
        \draw (16:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
        \draw (14:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
        \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(50:1cm)$);
        \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
        %
        \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$ \delta $}};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E)
        pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm,
        "\textcolor{red}{$\alpha$}", pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D)
        pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm,
        "\textcolor{dark green}{$\beta$}", pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)
        pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20, angle radius=1cm,
        "\textcolor{orange}{$\gamma$}", pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
        %
        \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
        \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
        \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
        \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
        \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm, right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};
        
        \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(50:1cm);
        \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);
        
        \draw [thick, dark blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 50, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
        \draw [thick, plum] (50:1cm) arc [start angle = 50, end angle = 90, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ >\frac{\pi}{6} $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\captionof{figure}{Angles $ \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta $} that correspond to $ a,b,c,d $ respectively. $ \varepsilon $ represents a positive infinitesimal.
\label{angles}

\end{minipage}
```

Also, in each `tikzpicture` I had to define the same coodinates `(A)`, `(B)`, `(C)` and `(D)`.

Is there a better way to do this, within the same `tikzpicture`?

It may seem relatively trivial and unnecessary to search for an alternative solution in this case, but this is just because the intended positioning is simple here: two drawings, one next to the other. But imagine we had to place three, four images, and had to position them in a special way—each image in the vertex of a regular polygon, for example.

## Edit: Preamble for compiling code

I put in all of the packages used in my document so I don't have to find out, by tedious trial-and-error, what's the minimal set for compiling the code above.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[symbol, perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\author{Paolo Lammens}
\title{PROMYS - Problem Set Solutions}



\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}


\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, angles, arrows}

\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\definecolor{dbwrru}{rgb}{0.8588235294117647,0.3803921568627451,0.0784313725490196}
\definecolor{dtsfsf}{rgb}{0.8274509803921568,0.1843137254901961,0.1843137254901961}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{dark blue}{HTML}{002663}
\definecolor{dark green}{HTML}{085e23}
\definecolor{plum}{HTML}{3d085e}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=dark blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the subfig package or any related package?

Comment: As for your second question, you could store the common parts of the Ti*k*Z pictures in some macro which you re-use and then you'd only have to worry about the new parts. This will allow you to make global changes more easily.

Comment: use `subcaption` instead of `subfig`

Comment: And if you want get a more detailed answer, you may want to promote your snippet to an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I fail to make your code compilable, and other might have the same problem.

Comment: You can also use the `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`

Comment: `subcaption` (or the older `subfig`) is really only useful if you want numbered captions for each subfigure. If you don't want that they are completely pointless.

Comment: @BambOo Isn't `groupplots` (and `pgfplots` in general) catered more towards creating function graphs, and not any image in general?

Comment: Yes, in this case it doesn't seem to be the right solution for you. That's why I did not put this in my solution. However it is quite powerful when dealing with multiple axis environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT n°2** : as it is not recommended to nest tikzpictures, you may use `scope` environments instead. I update the second snippet accordingly.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \begin{scope}[]
            \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(60:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
            \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$ \delta $}};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20, angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
            \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
            \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
            \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
            \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
            \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm, right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};
            \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(60:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);
            \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 60, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ \frac{\pi}{6} - \varepsilon $};
            \draw (46:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (44:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (76:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (74:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (16:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
            \draw (14:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,yshift=2cm]
            \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(50:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
            \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$     \delta $}};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle     radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20,     angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20,     angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
            \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
            \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
            \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
            \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
            \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm,     right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};
            \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(50:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);
            \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 50, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
            \draw [thick] (50:1cm) arc [start angle = 50, end angle = 90, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ >\frac{\pi}{6} $};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Two figures \label{fig:figure}}
    \end{figure}
    Two figures next to each other
\end{document}
```

A first answer with the `subcaption` package as advised by @percusse. I had to remove some fetaures of your snipppet to make it compilable, bu you have the idea of what to do.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{5cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
            \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(60:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
            \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$ \delta $}};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20, angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};  
            \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
            \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
            \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
            \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
            \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm, right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};

            \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(60:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);

            \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 60, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ \frac{\pi}{6} - \varepsilon $};

            \draw (46:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (44:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (76:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (74:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (16:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
            \draw (14:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Left subfigure \label{fig:lsubfig}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{5cm}
         \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
                \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
                \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
                \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(50:1cm)$);
                \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
                \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$     \delta $}};
                \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle     radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20,     angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
                \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20,     angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
                \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
                \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
                \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
                \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
                \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
                \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm,     right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};

                \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(50:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);

                \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 50, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
                \draw [thick] (50:1cm) arc [start angle = 50, end angle = 90, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ >\frac{\pi}{6} $};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Right subfigure \label{fig:rsubfig}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Two figures \label{fig:figure}}
    \end{figure}
    Two figures next to each other 

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** : if you really need to position them in a weird fashion, you can nest your `tikzpicture`s inside some `node`s and position them relativley to one another. I don't know if it is useful in you case or even recommended, but it might help.

Comment: Please don't encourage nesting of `tikzpicture`s, it can often cause problems, and is also completely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first edit, I was not sure about this. I guess using `scope` environments is more TiKzy right ?

Comment: Thanks! I think you forgot the `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]` before the first `\begin{scope}[]`, though.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, i will correct it promptly.

Comment: Could I ask you to put your **Edit nº2** section uptop, so that it is the first thing to be read from your answer? It's the part that best suits the intention of this question

Comment: That's Done !!!

Answer (score 4):

- for base of your images i use code from my answer on your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422818/wrapfigure-environment-not-placing-figure-within-text-inside-proof-environment)
- to make the code for complete figure shorter i define new command which contain common part of both images
- images are positioned by `\centering` and `\hfil` between them:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            labelfont=bf, font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\input{insbox}%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TeX macro,
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows,
                calc,
                quotes,
                }
\usepackage{siunitx}    % to write units. also defines `\ degree`

\definecolor{dark blue}{HTML}{002663}
\definecolor{dark green}{HTML}{085e23}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
\newcommand\ANGLES{ % <--- collected the common code of both images
\coordinate[label=below right:1]    (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:
            \textcolor{blue}{$\delta $}] (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate                         (C) at ($(B)+(30:1cm)$);
\coordinate                         (D) at ($(B)+(60:1cm)$);
\coordinate                         (E) at ($(B)+(90:1cm)$);
% axis
\draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
\draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
% angles
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (E)
    pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm,
        "\textcolor{red}{$\alpha$}",
        pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}]  {angle = A--B--E};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (D)
    pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm,
        "\textcolor{dark green}{$\beta$}",
        pic text options={above=.1cm}]              {angle = A--B--D};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)
    pic [draw=purple!50!black, fill=purple!20, angle radius=1cm,
        "\textcolor{orange!50!black}{$\gamma$}",
        pic text options={right=.05mm}]             {angle = A--B--C};
% circle
\clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
\draw (B) circle [radius=1cm];
\fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
\draw [thick] (A) +(0,0.5mm) -- + (0,-0.5mm);
% angle lines
\draw [very thick, blue]    (B) -- +(0:1cm);
\draw [very thick, purple]  (B) -- +(30:1cm);
\draw [very thick, green]   (B) -- +(60:1cm);
\draw [very thick, red]     (B) -- +(90:1cm);
            } %%%%% end of command ANGLES

    \centering
%%%% left image
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\ANGLES
% arc labels
\path   (A) arc ( 0:30:1cm) node[midway,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {$\|$};
\draw [thick, dark blue] (C) arc (30:60:1cm)
        node[midway,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {$\|$}
        node [midway,sloped,above] {\small $ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
\path   (E) arc (90:60:1cm) node[midway,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {$\|$};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\hfil %%%% distance between images
%%%% right image  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\ANGLES
% arc labels
\draw [thick, dark blue] (C) arc (30:60:1cm)
        node[midway,sloped,above,font=\small] {$ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
\path   (E) arc (90:60:1cm)
        node[midway,sloped,above,font=\small] {$ >\frac{\pi}{6} $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ that correspond to $a,b,c,d$ respectively. $\varepsilon$ represents a positive infinitesimal.}
\label{angles}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! Just one little thing: in the second figure, the green angle is smaller than in the first figure, so we would have to put the respective commands out of the common `\ANGLES` command.

Comment: By the way, great improvement on using the `\path   (E) arc (90:60:1cm) node[midway,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {$\|$};` expression to add the double lines on the arcs; I didn't know about it, thanks

Comment: Very nice. zARKO...+1.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a table, you can place the two `tikzpictures` next to each other like any other letter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
            \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(60:1cm)$);
            \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
            \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$ \delta $}};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20, angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};  
            \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
            \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
            \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
            \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
            \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm, right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};

            \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(60:1cm);
            \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);

            \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 60, radius = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ \frac{\pi}{6} - \varepsilon $};

            \draw (46:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (44:1cm) -- +(225:1pt) -- +(45:1pt);
            \draw (76:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (74:1cm) -- +(255:1pt) -- +(75:1pt);
            \draw (16:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
            \draw (14:1cm) -- +(195:1pt) -- +(15:1pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{1cm}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
                \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
                \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (C) at ($ (0,0) +(30:1cm)$);
                \coordinate (D) at ($ (0,0) +(50:1cm)$);
                \coordinate (E) at ($ (0,0) +(90:1cm)$);
                \draw (0,0) node [right=0.2cm, below=0.5mm] {\textcolor{blue}{$     \delta $}};
                \draw (A) -- (B) -- (E) pic [draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20, angle     radius=2.4cm, pic text options={left=5.5mm, above=.3cm}] {angle = A--B--E};
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (D) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20,     angle radius=1.7cm, pic text options={above=.1cm}] {angle = A--B--D};
                \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) pic [draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20,     angle radius=1cm, pic text options={right=.05mm}] {angle = A--B--C};
                \clip (-0.2, -0.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
                \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
                \fill [white] (0.95, -0.1) rectangle (1.05, 0.1);
                \draw (0, -0.2) -- (0,1.2);
                \draw (-0.2, 0) -- (1.2,0);
                \draw [thick] (A) -- +(90:0.5mm) -- +(270:0.5mm) node [below=.2mm,     right=.1 mm] {$ 1 $};

                \draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) -- +(0:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, orange] (0,0) -- +(30:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, green] (0,0) -- +(50:1cm);
                \draw [very thick, red] (0,0) -- +(90:1cm);

                \draw [thick, blue] (C) arc [start angle = 30, end angle = 50, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ <\frac{\pi}{6} $};
                \draw [thick] (50:1cm) arc [start angle = 50, end angle = 90, radius     = 1cm] node [midway, sloped, above] {\small $ >\frac{\pi}{6} $};
            \end{tikzpicture}
          \caption{Angles $ \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta $ that correspond to $ a,b,c,d $ respectively. $ \varepsilon $ represents a positive infinitesimal.}
    \end{figure}
    Two figures next to each other 

\end{document}
```

*(As your code did not compile even after adding the obvious missing packages, I used the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423061/36296)*